# Issue with Large sql query in asp.net webpages

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

Hi Hope someone can help.

I am trying to render a list of all my product url's I am using ASP.NET WEBpages (not WebForms or MVC).

But if the Database query is over a certain amount of records it gives me the following error.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a null reference

If I put into the SQL query Top 500 it works fine.

my db query

```
var db = Database.Open("MyConnectionString");
var Products = "SELECT Top 500* FROM shop_products WHERE site_id = '99' AND product_active = 'Y' ORDER BY product_name ASC";
```

I used to be able to do this in Classic ASP.

Might there be a limit on SQL query sizes in asp.net, If so how do i get around this.

Help

Comment: How many records do you have on database

Comment: Have tried adding "Connect Timeout" in your connection string?

Comment: Hi there only about 1500 products to call.

Comment: Really?  Which line of code is throwing that exception ?  Are you binding the results from this SQL to a particular control  (if so, where is that code ?)

Comment: I would guess that some data that you bind to is null (well dbnull at least) in one or more of the records and the binding throws an exception

Comment: I am using the asp.net razor Database helper. This is the only thing i cant seam to do.

Comment: I have added a photo of the error.

Comment: run the query in sql server management studio, is friendlyurl null in any of the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key phrase in the error message is "cannot perform runtime binding on a **null** reference".

I suspect that the top 500 rows in the "shop_products" table did not have a column value with a NULL value. That is why that select worked and the select without the "top 500" qualifier did not.

Your code needs to detect DBnull values and assign a default value for these cases or do some sort of error processing to avoid this runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I split this down into smaller SQL query's, split out by the category's the products where in.